# create a binary tree for alphabetical equation

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I have to create a binary tree to get the valid sentences out of list of tokens.

example :- 
I have a set of tokens - ['(', 'one', '.', 'two', '.', '(', 'zero', '|', 'o', ')', '.', 'six', ')']

and from that I want to obtains result of sentences as follows:-

one two zero six

one two o six

Here "." means concatenation connecting operator , "()" - required grouping operator,"|" or connecting operator , [] - optional grouping operator

I already created tokens from alphabetical equation.But I am not able to create a proper binary tree structure so that I can create a tree in such a way that whenever I traverse the tree I get these sentences out of tokens

code of binary tree I can write but I am stuck in creating logic for the same

another example will be:-

input - ['(', '(', '(', 'one', '.', 'two', ')', '|', 'twelve', ')', '.', '(', 'zero', '|', 'o', ')', '.', 'six', ')']

output-

one two zero six

one two o six

twelve o six

Comment: if your intention to parse out words from the token, you could use 'trie'. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie

Comment: No, I want to make full sentences out of tokens, words are already there as tokens :/ if that makes sense

Comment: Could output be: twelve zero six

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's useful to look at this as an equation parser. What you have is this equation:

```
(("one" . "two") | "twelve") . (("zero" | "0") . "six")
```

You can then build the tree from the bottom. `("one" . "two")` looks like this:

```
            .
         /     \
      "one"   "two"
```

"twelve", of course, is a node all by itself. And to complete the first part, you put the "|" as a parent node, like this:

```
             |
         /       \
       .       "twelve" 
    /     \
 "one"   "two"
```

That gives you `(("one" . "two") | "twelve")`.

You do the same kind of thing with the other half of the equation, and add a "." operator as the root node.

There is a formal way of building the tree while you're parsing, using a modification of the [Shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: thanks for the help!! I want to ask how shall I traverse the tree to obtain sentences out of it, which traversal order shall I use

Comment: @TinMah The understanding for the `.` operator is left to right. So for the root node you would traverse the left node and then the right node. For `|`, you pick one of the branches, and traverse it.